# JavaScript- Changing font and size of the code result

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am using a code to give me a word, letter, whatever we want radomly starting from a list created by me. My question is, how to change the font and size of the words?
 I thank you all for the help you can give me. (some code words are in Portuguese so do not bind)
Here is the code,

```
<div id="abc">
<script type="text/javascript">
var c="Piso 2, lugar A1";
var d="Piso 3, lugar A2";
var e="Piso 1, lugar A3";
var thing = window['cde'.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*3))];
document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = "Reservado em " + thing;
document.getElementById("abc").setAttribute("style",     "position:absolute;top:20px;left:20px")
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to change the font-size and font only for the word that is in variable `thing` ? or you want whole word to be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already doing it right. just try to add some more style like:

```
document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = "Reservado em <span style='font-size:30px;font-family:Times New Roman;'>" + thing+"</span>";
document.getElementById("abc").setAttribute("style", "position:absolute;top:20px;left:20px")
```

In this way you can add as many as you want attributes in the style.

Answer (score 0):

wrap in `span` and add style:

```
var myText = "blablabla";
var largeText = "<span style='font-size:50px;'>"+myText+"</span>"
var timesNewRomanText = "<span style='font-family:Times New Roman;'>"+myText+"</span>"
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp

EDIT:

here is an example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/hpydT/)

Comment: It's not working, probably I'm doing something wrong, can you show me how the all code looks like? Thank's for answering!